# Docker container doesn't start up

Tags: docker

SCNEARIO:

A custom image with the following Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 7070
CMD [ "npm", "start"]
```

I can build the image just typing docker build . (from the project's folder). But... always exists a but :-( When I execute:

```
docker run -d --restart=always <imageid>
```

The container is created fine but....

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  
CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS               
NAMES
4314ffc2afcb        a68faf70e589        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   20 
minutes ago      Restarting (0) 44 seconds ago                       
magical_hopper
```

Sorry for the bad indentation, to sum up, I don't have idea WHY? the container it's not UP.

I think that the problem is on the Dockerfile.

PD: I know that this issue can be duplicated but I don't understood the solutions (I am newbie using docker, excuse me).

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance to everybody.

Comment: What is the output of this command : docker logs 4314ffc2afcb

Comment: also check and share `docker  inspect  4314ffc2afcb `

Comment: what's the content of docker-entrypoint.sh file?

Comment: @Arik docker-entrypoint.sh is empty :(

Comment: @Nico docker logs doesn't shows nothing

Comment: @fly2matrix This return a big json file.... can you precise a little more?

Comment: there must be a section on the top part in json .. that must be specifying reason for container startup actions.

Comment: @fly2matrix  "State": {
            "Status": "restarting",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": true,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 0,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2019-10-18T12:22:36.1459445Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2019-10-18T12:22:36.3738208Z"
        },

Comment: @MadDev ok in the documentation of command docker logs it is written "If your image runs a non-interactive process such as a web server or a database, that application may send its output to log files instead of STDOUT and STDERR". Maybe you're in this case.

Comment: try executing `npm start` command inside the new container. `docker run -it <imageid> sh` . You will get some hint about the issue

Answer (score 0):

Ok -- issue is with `entrypoint` and `cmd` both are defined.
at the end it's equivalent command would be `docker-entrypoint.sh  npm  start`.

`npm` and `start` are passed as an argument to `docker-entrypoint.sh` script.
It will not start npm and hence it will come out of container immediately.

Try first removing ENTRYPOINT from your Dockerfile
or
use docker-entrypoint.sh to include `npm start` command at the end.

Comment: I tried the two options, I removed the ENTRYPOINT and I built the container but it stills with the status "Exited (0)". Also I create a relly simple script to execute npm start (with CMD ["npm","start"] removed) and still not wotking. I am absolutely blocked :-(

Comment: So I think that this Dockefile is correct FROM node:10
    WORKDIR /usr/src/app
    COPY package*.json ./
    RUN npm install
    COPY . .
    EXPOSE 7070
    # ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
    CMD [ "npm", "start"]

Comment: can we chat somewhere - live so that I can help you right away ?

Comment: Join this chat-room.
https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100102/docker